# Не импортируются классы в Intelijj IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Клонирую git репозиторий и никакие пакеты не импортируются, sdk установлено, idea подгрузила свои файлы, не понимаю в чем проблема.
При этом приложение деплоится и работает нормально.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: SDK настроен? File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Project SDK

Comment: Сброс кешей не помог?

Comment: Не пробовал. Помогла переустановка, при переустановке кеши чистятся, скорее всего можно было бы их руками почистить без переустановки и возможно заработало бы.

Answer (score 1):

Единственное что помогло так это переустановка Intelijj IDEA, пробовал разные способы в том числе из ответов на английском stackoverflow.